# Is there an APL idiom to get a vector of all alphabetical characters?

Tags: cross-platform, apl

I know you can get a character vector of all numbers with `∊⍕¨⍳10`, but is there a platform independent idiom for getting a vector of all alphabetical characters, aside from manually typing `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`? I know that I can do `⎕AV[(⍳26)+(⎕AV⍳'a')-1]` to get all lowercase characters (and uppercase by changing the `'a'` to `'A'`) in Dyalog APL, but I presume the system variable `⎕AV` isn't available in other environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.

In Dyalog APL, what I generally do is use `⎕A` for the uppercase characters and `⎕UCS 96+⍳26` for the lowercase characters. (And `⎕A,⎕UCS 96+⍳26` for the whole alphabet.)

`⎕AV` is usually present, but its contents are not standard. (For example, NARS2000's `⎕AV` is different from Dyalog's.) By the way, in Dyalog `⎕AV` is considered deprecated in favour of `⎕UCS`. Any APL that implements `⎕UCS` will do it the same way, because Unicode is a set standard.

If you want a guaranteed implementation-independent, readable way to define the alphabet I would indeed recommend to just store `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` in your workspace.

However, I would not recommend trying to write implementation-independent APL code to begin with. APL dialects are rather divergent, so this is decidedly nontrivial (if possible at all for complex code), and will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Are you taking part in the Dyalog Competition this year?

Answer (score 2):

Even though Quad names (`⎕xxx`) are usually case insensitive, MicroAPL distinguishes between `⎕A` and `⎕a`, so `⎕a,⎕A` gives `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the latest versions*, write `⎕A,⎕C⎕A`, for `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

[Try APL online!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%E2%8E%95A%2C%E2%8E%95C%E2%8E%95A&run)

[Documentation.](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/System%20Functions/c.htm)

---

<sup>* 18.0 and up.</sup>